# Google Cloud - Moving MySQL DB Location to Attached Disk

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Cloud vm instance running and I set it up with an additional attached disk. I then installed mysql successfully but I can't seem to figure out how to move the MySQL db store location to the attached disk.

Does anyone know how to do this? It is a Linux based vm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the query below to lookup MySQL directories values:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir";
```

In your GCE VM instance the directories should look like:

```
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                      |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| basedir                   | /usr                       |
| character_sets_dir        | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| datadir                   | /var/lib/mysql/            |
| innodb_data_home_dir      |                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./                         |
| lc_messages_dir           | /usr/share/mysql/          |
| plugin_dir                | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/     |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /tmp                       |
| tmpdir                    | /tmp                       |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

follow the answer of this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137424/moving-mysql-datadir) to move the 'datadir' to your secondary disk.